# How to add graphics to map centre in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I am using the following code to add point graphics to the map center whenever there is an extent change, how ever the point remains at [0,0] and doesnt change with change in extent. How can I fix this?

```
map.on('moveend',function(evt){
    var map=evt.map;
      var extent1=map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
    var b= getCenter(extent1);
    var c=transform(b, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var lon=c[0].toFixed(1);
    var lat=c[1].toFixed(1);
    var point_feature = new ol.Feature({ });
    var point_geom = new ol.geom.Point(
      [lon,lat]
    );
    point_feature.setGeometry(point_geom);
    var vector_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [point_feature]
      })
    })
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#3399CC'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 4
        }),
        radius: 8
      }),
    });  
    map.addLayer(vector_layer);
    vector_layer.setStyle(style);
  })
```

Comment: @TomazicM's answer is correct for the code being used, but using the `moveend` event might not be the best approach as the graphic will update only after you finish panning.  If you want a graphic always fixed at the center while panning you can get a much smoother effect using the vectorContext at the `postrender` event, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/scalerings-4zfij (that example uses geodesic geometry so it does need to convert to and from lon/lat).

Answer (score 2):

Coordinates should always be given in CRS of the map view. With the call

```
var extent1 = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

you are getting extent in the current view CRS, so there is no need to transform coordinates. Instead of your `[lon, lat]` coordinates, just use your calculated center coordinate `b`:

```
var extent1 = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var b = ol.extent.getCenter(extent1);
var point_feature = new ol.Feature({ });
var point_geom = new ol.geom.Point(b);
```